# authentication using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

i have written a stored procedure for user authentication in SQL, how should i get the return value from this procedure later in my c#.Net code to enable the user to log in ?

```
create procedure userLogin_proc
@userName nvarchar(45),
@passCode nvarchar(20)

as
begin

select userName,passCode from userLogin where username = @userName and passCode = @passCode
end
```

Comment: how do you access your database in your server side code? Are you using ADO.NET? Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: If this is a production environment, you shouldn't store pass codes in the clear.  Hash the pass codes, store the hash, and compare the hash of the user-entered password with the stored hash.  Also consider using salts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use output parameter to return userid, if login successful, user id will be returned, else 0 will be returned

```
create procedure userLogin_proc
@userName nvarchar(45),
@passCode nvarchar(20)
@UserId int=0 OUTPUT
as
begin

select @UserId =id from userLogin where username = @userName and passCode = @passCode
end
```

and on C# side do this after ExecuteReader:

```
SqlDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
int UserId = (int)cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value;
```

you can read more about output parameters here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/136351/How-to-retrieve-output-parameter-from-Store-proced

Comment: can you explain the usage of 'OUTPUT' word in your code ?

Comment: it is keyword when we write we mean that this parameter will be returned in output by stored procedure after its execution

Comment: you can read more on web about output parameter and can see examples lkie here:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/136351/How-to-retrieve-output-parameter-from-Store-proced

Answer (score 1):

Change it to a `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM userLogin....` and then use `ExecuteScalar()` on the SqlDataReader object.

As a side note, it's not a good idea to store your passwords in the DB in plain text, but hash them instead, preferably with a salt value.

Comment: can you give an example of how to hash the password ?@Wim

Comment: There are tons of examples on SO on this already, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hash+password+c%23

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the plain text password in the database. Look up a hashing method.In my example below i use `SHA256`.

```
class User
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public User(string userName, string plainTextPassword)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.Password = GetHash(plainTextPassword);
    }
    public string GetHash(string toHash)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHash))).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
    public void Save() { /* Save UserName and the Hashed Password to database */ }
    public bool ValidateLogin(string userNameEntered, string passwordEntered)
    {
        string userName; string password = string.Empty;
        string ConnectionString = "Your Connection String";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string CommandText = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM userLogin WHERE Username = @UserName";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = userNameEntered;
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    userName = rdr["UserName"].ToString();
                    password = rdr["Password"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        if (password.Equals(GetHash(passwordEntered))) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This example shows a crude example of hashing as well as retrieving from the database.